# PHP EXIF data not working

Tags: php, metadata, exif

I am new to PHP, and adapting a script from http://www.techrepublic.com/article/create-a-dynamic-photo-gallery-with-php-in-three-steps/ which generates a table of images in a directory along with some accompanying EXIF data. The only problem is that the code has not display the EXIF data. This happens with even the original source code. My best guess of what is happening is that something in the original source code is old and outdated, and no longer supported by modern PHP. I have made sure that my server has EXIF enabled.

Here's the code:

```
<table>
<?php
// define directory path
$dir = "path/to/directory";

// iterate through files
// look for JPEGs
if (is_dir($dir)) {
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
      if (preg_match("/.jpg/", $file)) {

        // read EXIF headers
        $exif = exif_read_data($file, 0, true);

        // get image
        echo "<tr><td rowspan='3'><img src='$dir/$file'></td>";

        // get file name
        echo "<th>Title</th><td>" . $exif['FILE']['FileName'] . "</td></tr>";

        // get timestamp
        echo "<tr><th>Year</th><td>"  . $exif['IFD0']['DateTime'] . "</td></tr>";

        // get image dimensions
        echo "<tr><th>Description</th><td>" . $exif['IFD0']['Comments'] . "</td></tr>";

      }
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
?>
</table>
```

**EDIT:** I also get the following error logs:

```
20160815T185355: benxd.me/art/gallery.php 
PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(): Unable to open file in /hermes/walnaweb01a/b893/pow.hdemoras/htdocs/benxd/art/gallery.php on line 21 
PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(): Unable to open file in /hermes/walnaweb01a/b893/pow.hdemoras/htdocs/benxd/art/gallery.php on line 21 
PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(): Unable to open file in /hermes/walnaweb01a/b893/pow.hdemoras/htdocs/benxd/art/gallery.php on line 21 
PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(): Unable to open file in /hermes/walnaweb01a/b893/pow.hdemoras/htdocs/benxd/art/gal
```

In my code line 21 is `$exif = exif_read_data($file, 0, true);`

Comment: Have you inspected `$exif` and read the documentation on `exif_read_data()`?

Comment: Do the images have exif data?

Comment: Yes, I have read the documentation at php.net, but it does not make too much sense to me besides examples I have seen.

Comment: They do have exif data.  I have used _Example #1 exif_read_data()_ example at [http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php) to validate exif data is present.

Comment: I have a real server path, but have  used an example for purposes of the question.

Comment: Have you checked your Error logs?

Comment: Does the table output any of the `.jpg` files into the table, but EXIF data missing? Or nothing is output to the table?

Comment: All the `.jpg` files are outputted into the table

Comment: I am looking at the error logs and I see `PHP Warning:  exif_read_data(): Unable to open file in /hermes/walnaweb01a/b893/pow.hdemoras/htdocs/benxd/art/gallery.php on line 21` Line 21 is directly under `// read EXIF headers`

Comment: Might need to set file permissions to `0755` or `0777`. Might also need to change owning user/group for the image files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try explicitly adding the full path and the list of sections:

```
$exif = exif_read_data($dir . $file, "FILE,COMPUTED,ANY_TAG,IFD0,THUMBNAIL,COMMENT,EXIF", true);
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Comment: Thanks! `$exif = exif_read_data("$dir/$file", "FILE,COMPUTED,ANY_TAG,IFD0,THUMBNAIL,COMMENT,EXIF", true);` works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I spent weeks with this problem, so in the end I decided to create a library to extract the metadata (Exif, XMP, GPS...) from a PNG in PHP, 100% native, I hope it helps. :) [PNGMetadata](https://github.com/joserick/PNGMetadata)

[image]